# Filtering on joins with two foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Say I have two tables, `users` and `addresses` (contains columns `id` and `text`). I have two address columns in `users`, say `temp_address_id` and `permanent_address_id`.

If I want to get add the users with temp_address = 'SF' **or** permanent_address = 'MTV', is the following query the only way out?

```
SELECT * FROM users
JOIN addresses ON (
  (users.temp_address_id = addresses.id AND addresses.text = 'SF')
  OR (users.permanent_address_id = addresses.id AND addresses.text = 'MTV')
)
```

I don't think there is a way to specify the filters (`addresses.text = 'SF'` and `addresses.text = 'MTV'`) in the `WHERE` clause. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the users, I would recommend two `exists`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM addresses a
              WHERE u.temp_address_id = a.id AND a.text = 'SF'
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM addresses a
              WHERE u.permanent_address_id = a.id AND a.text = 'MTV'
             );
```

This should have much better performance than `OR` in the `JOIN` clause, especially with an index on `addresses(id, text)`.

If you need address information returned, use two `left join`s:

```
SELECT u.*, COALECE(ta.text, tp.text) as text
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     addresses ta
     ON u.temp_address_id = ta.id AND
        ta.text = 'SF' LEFT JOIN
     addresses tp
     ON u.permanent_address_id = ta.id AND
        ta.text = 'MTV'
WHERE ta.id IS NOT NULL OR tp.id IS NOT NULL;
```

The downside to this approach is that you need to use `COALESCE()` for each of the columns selected from the `address` table.

Comment: ah! can you explain why the subqueries would be faster? I may have nested joins so I'm curious whether nested subqueries would still be faster.

Comment: @YashMittal . . . The `EXISTS` subqueries are probably the fastest method -- if you don't need columns from `addresses`.  They can make direct use of the index mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Changed join condition to include both addresses.

Why can't you do following? Have you tried it?

```
SELECT u.*,COALESCE(a.text,b.text) AS text
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN addresses a ON u.temp_address_id = a.id AND a.text = 'SF'
LEFT JOIN addresses b ON u.permanent_address_id = b.id AND b.text = 'MTV';
```

Comment: If the temp_address of a user is 'MTV', it will show up in your join. If the permanent_address of a user is 'MTV' and the temp_address is neither of the two, it will not show up in your join.

Comment: I see. I missed that both addresses are different. You need to use `left join` for this.